# Extract part of a filename to a variable

Tags: linux, bash, filenames

I am working in linux bash.
I have a filename which is captured by a script into this var ($filename).
The filename is something like this:
release-10.20.30.tar.xz

I want to be able to capture the numeric part, into a VAR.
This is: 10.20.30

How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can use awk. Here it will be:

```
filename=$(echo "$filename" | awk -F "-" '{print $2}' | awk -F ".tar" '{print $1}')
```

here you tkae the second iteration of the char "-" and the first of ".tar".
Second awk could be replace by awk -F "." '{print $1,.,$2,.,$3}'

or use it directly when you set the value of $filename

Comment: Unfortunately, this has [broken quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) and an inefficient and inelegant double Awk. Probably try http://shellcheck.net/ for basic diagnostics.

Comment: just update for the double quote

Comment: The double Awk is still a bit of a wart. Avoiding an external process with a parameter expansion is generally the most efficient solution, though slightly more verbose than e.g. `grep -Eo '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*'`. But this has been answered many, many times before.